# AsyncTask.execute() returns null

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using the below code to get the version from json

**webservice.java**

```
public void getSingleResponse(final String url) {
        class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String resp;
                resp = "";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    Log.d("URL", "" + params[0]);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(
                            params[0]));
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    Log.d("Entity ", "" + entity);
                    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity,
                            "UTF-8");
                    resp = responseString;
                    GlobalVar.Version = resp;
                    Log.v("Global Version", "" + GlobalVar.Version);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.v("HTTP:::::", "error" + e.getCause());
                }
                return GlobalVar.Version;
            }
        }
        new task().execute(url);
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public static String getMarketVersion() throws JSONException {
        String version = "";
        try {
            webservice ws = new webservice();
            String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "/GetVersion";
            Log.i(TAG, "Server URL" + serverUrl);

            ws.getSingleResponse(serverUrl);
            String response = GlobalVar.Version;
            Log.v("Response :: ", "Version ::" + response);

            JSONArray jArry = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject jObj = jArry.getJSONObject(0);
            version = jObj.getString("Version");

            Log.v("Parsing ", "Version :: " + version);
            return version;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return version;
    }
```

when i **Run** the application i got the **Version Blank** see the log below

```
07-24 12:27:42.309: V/Response ::(4268): Version ::
07-24 12:27:43.389: V/Global Version(4268): [{"Version":"1.1.3"}]
```

but when i **Debug** the application i am able to **get the response**

```
07-24 12:06:01.699: V/Global Version(3122): [{"Version":"1.1.3"}]
07-24 12:06:07.349: V/Response ::(3122): Version ::[{"Version":"1.1.3"}]
07-24 12:08:12.019: V/Parsing(3122): Version :: 1.1.3
```

i don't know whats going on 
thanks in advance

Comment: async task is async. but you think it's not.

Comment: yaa but only debug time not runtime.how can i get same response in runtime ?

Comment: when you debug, you stop some threads, and get result.

Comment: so any help to implement the code in runtime ?

Comment: google any example. async task has special method where you should use task's result.

Comment: i am still not able to get the version. any code or example to implement my task ?

Comment: Why is your asynctask class inside of the method ?

Comment: bcoz i have no **onCreate()** to execute the asynctask

Answer (score 1):

First try to understand, How asyncTask works? `doInBackground` works in different thread from your UI Thread, and after execute the asynctask you have to wait until it complete, means you need to override `OnPostExecute` method of asynctask and there you will get your version, and BTW you should not share things using static variable in android , android provide various methods to do that

Comment: first i am `public String getSingleResponse(final String url)` and returning the version. but the same problem occurs so i used the global variable.

Comment: @user2582308 you're not returning anything

Comment: and you are not public String ... :)

Comment: i did it bt still same problem

Comment: what changes you did?

Answer (score 1):

As Kapil Vats said, you should do it different way.

For example, create your own class and extend it 
`YourHttpGetter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

Create an Interface with some method like this

```
public void onTaskComplete(T result);
```

In the constructor of YourHttpGetter class, pass a reference of ur class (Activity) that is going to implement that Interface.

Override `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`, in this last one, execute `activityImplementingInterface.onTaskComplete(result);`

And of course, in your activity implement interface's method

```
@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String json) { do whatever you need }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Method in your AsyncTask class.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            GlobalVar.Version = result;
        }
```

Comment: It won't help in his case ) Since he performs operations with `GlobalVar.Version` right away, after the task is started